# Swift: how can String.join() work custom types?

Tags: swift

for example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]    // Ints
var s = ",".join(a)  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Is it possible to make the join function return "1,2,3" ?

Extend Int (or other custom types) to conform to some protocols ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]    // Ints
var s = ",".join(a.map { $0.description })
```

or add this extension

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Printable>(elements: S) -> String {
        return self.join(map(elements){ $0.description })
    }

  // use this if you don't want it constrain to Printable
  //func join<S : SequenceType>(elements: S) -> String {
  //    return self.join(map(elements){ "\($0)" })
  //}
}

var a = [1, 2, 3]    // Ints
var s = ",".join(a)  // works with new overload of join
```

---

join is defined as

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where String == String>(elements: S) -> String
}
```

which means it takes a sequence of string, you can't pass a sequence of int to it.

Comment: I do not like the second un-commented suggestion. It doesn't seem robust or generic enough. Seems wrong to rely on description like that. Also the commented option (using \($0)) is not amazing IMO. It opens you up to an implicit conversion to string while using the "join" operation. Users won't even know that it happened. Simply using in-place mapping is more verbose and more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 43):

From **Xcode 7.0 beta 6** in **Swift 2** now you should use `[String].joinWithSeparator(",")`.
In your case you still need to change Int to String type, therefore I added `map()`.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]                                       // [1, 2, 3]
var s2 = a.map { String($0) }.joinWithSeparator(",")    // "1,2,3"
```

From **Xcode 8.0 beta 1** in **Swift 3** code slightly changes to
`[String].joined(separator: ",")`.

```
var s3 = a.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: ",")    // "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 10):

And just to make your life more complete, starting from **Xcode 8.0 beta 1** in **Swift 3** you should NOW use `[String].joined(separator: ",")`.

This is the new "ed/ing" naming rule for Swift APIs:

> **Name functions and methods according to their side-effects**
>
> - Those without side-effects should read as noun phrases, e.g. x.distance(to: y), i.successor().
> - Those with side-effects should read as imperative verb phrases, e.g., print(x), x.sort(), x.append(y).
> - Name Mutating/nonmutating method pairs consistently. A mutating method will often have a nonmutating variant with similar semantics, but that returns a new value rather than updating an instance in-place.
>     [Swift: API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#strive-for-fluent-usage)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is a variation of @BryanChen's answer:

```
",".join(a.map { String($0) } )
```

Comment: This is better than using `description` whose result is not guaranteed. `String()` is guaranteed to produce a `String`.

Comment: @Zaph what do you mean by "result is not guaranteed"??

Comment: The `description` field is used to provide a human readable description. For `Int` is usually a conversion of the number to its string representation. But being it a (computed) property, it can be overridden, although that's unlikely to happen for an `Int`.

Comment: Additionally Apple can change the description, there is no guarantee as to it's format. As an example the description of NSDictionaries take liberties of not quoting value strings in some instances and Swifr does not quote strings in Dictioaries. The description is not designed to be used in code, the format is not specifies in the documentation.

Comment: @Antonio I still don't understand. Does `String(1)` guarantee its value? and if you override (you can't for `Int`) `description`, you probably mean it (although it is a bad idea anyway)

Comment: String(1) is guaranteed to produce a string containing "1". Now `Int.description` returns "1", but it's possible that tomorrow Apple decides to change its implementation to return "(Int) 1", or something else. `description` is meant to provide a string description of an object, and not to convert an object to string. That said, if you still use `description`, today it works. Tomorrow it's possible it won't as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you can't make join work for custom types, there's an easy workaround.
All you have to do is define a method on your class (or extend a built-in class) to return a string, and then map that into the join.

So, for example, we could have:

```
extension Int {
    func toString() -> String {
        return "\(self)" // trivial example here, but yours could be more complex
    }
```

Then you can do:

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3]
let s = join(xs.map { $0.toString() })
```

I wouldn't recommend using `.description` for this purpose, as by default it will call `.debugDescription`, which is not particularly useful in production code.

In any case, it would be better to provide an explicit method for transforming into a string suitable for joining, rather than relying on a generic 'description' method which you may change at a later date.

Comment: `debugDescription` is intended for debugging, not `description`

Comment: @BryanChen That is true, but it's worth noting that the `NSObject` implementation of the latter calls the former.  I'll edit my post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

A Swift 3 solution

```
public extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: CustomStringConvertible {
    func joined(seperator: String) -> String {
        return self.map({ (val) -> String in
            "\(val)"
        }).joined(separator: seperator)
    }
}
```