# How do I convert a Swift Array to a String?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I know how to programmatically do it, but I'm sure there's a built-in way...

Every language I've used has some sort of default textual representation for a collection of objects that it will spit out when you try to concatenate the Array with a string, or pass it to a print() function, etc.  Does Apple's Swift language have a built-in way of easily turning an Array into a String, or do we always have to be explicit when stringifying an array?

Comment: *Swift 4:* `array.description` or if you want a custom separator `array.joined(separator: ",")`

Answer (score 830, accepted):

If the array contains strings, you can use the `String`'s `join` method:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let stringRepresentation = "-".join(array) // "1-2-3"
```

In **Swift 2**:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

let stringRepresentation = array.joinWithSeparator("-") // "1-2-3"
```

This can be useful if you want to use a specific separator (hyphen, blank, comma, etc).

Otherwise, you can simply use the `description` property, which returns a string representation of the array:

```
let stringRepresentation = [1, 2, 3].description // "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Hint: any object implementing the `Printable` protocol has a `description` property. If you adopt that protocol in your classes/structs, you make them print-friendly as well

In **Swift 3**

- `join` becomes `joined`, example `[nil, "1", "2"].flatMap({$0}).joined()`
- `joinWithSeparator` becomes `joined(separator:)` (only available to Array of Strings)

In **Swift 4**

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
array.joined(separator:"-")
```

Comment: I can't make this work `let stringRepresentation = "-".join(array)` Maybe it's related to Swift 1.2 update.

Comment: @Andrej: It works on both 1.2 and 2.0. Are you using an array of strings?

Comment: Antonio, sorry, my bad. I had an issue with my array. Now I can confirm your solution works. :)

Comment: Why is this called on the string and not the array? Seems backwards to me?! Whatever.

Comment: @AdamWaite because the output is a string - the array can contain anything, not just strings, whereas the join method expects an array of strings

Comment: `"-".join(array)` is no longer available in Swift 2, Xcode 7 Beta 6, try using `array.joinWithSeparator("-")`

Comment: `joinWithSeparator` is only available for array of strings. If you have array of other objects, then use `map` first. For example, `[1, 2, 3].map({"\($0)"}).joinWithSeparator(",")`

Comment: As of Swift 2 `Printable` was reamed to `CustomStringConvertible`

Comment: I wonder why `debugDescription` does not suffice? For me it looks like the most generic solution in that it works for all types of arrays.

Comment: @Dmitry Don't use string interpolation soley for conversion to string. It's much nicer to use an initializer on String

Comment: @Dmitry Are you sure that's the best way? By using `map` AND `joinWithSeparator`, aren't you iterating through the string twice when you only need to iterate once? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581324/swift-how-can-string-join-work-custom-types

Comment: @mattdipasquale yes, it will iterate the array twice, but `joinWithSeparator` is not available for string arrays. If it is critical to have only one iteration, then you'd need to write your own, or use `reduce`: `[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce("") { $0 + ($0.isEmpty ? "" : ", ") + String($1)}`. But it doesn't look very elegant. I think for small arrays `map` with `join` should be fine. The solution with `reduce` may create too many string objects

Comment: How can join the array starting from array index 1 ?

Comment: In Swift 3.0: You can use this 
'let join = "-"'
'let joinedString = array.joined(separator: join)'
print("joinedString: \(joinedString)") // Output is 1-2-3

Comment: self.TimeLongString = TimingArr.map({"\($0)"}).joined(separator: ",")

Answer (score 178):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the following Playground sample codes in order to solve your problem.

---

#### Turning an array of `Character`s into a `String` with no separator:

```
let characterArray: [Character] = ["J", "o", "h", "n"]
let string = String(characterArray)

print(string)
// prints "John"
```

---

#### Turning an array of `String`s into a `String` with no separator:

```
let stringArray = ["Bob", "Dan", "Bryan"]
let string = stringArray.joined(separator: "")

print(string) // prints: "BobDanBryan"
```

---

#### Turning an array of `String`s into a `String` with a separator between words:

```
let stringArray = ["Bob", "Dan", "Bryan"]
let string = stringArray.joined(separator: " ")

print(string) // prints: "Bob Dan Bryan"
```

---

#### Turning an array of `String`s into a `String` with a separator between characters:

```
let stringArray = ["car", "bike", "boat"]
let characterArray = stringArray.flatMap { $0 }
let stringArray2 = characterArray.map { String($0) }
let string = stringArray2.joined(separator: ", ")

print(string) // prints: "c, a, r, b, i, k, e, b, o, a, t"
```

---

#### Turning an array of `Float`s into a `String` with a separator between numbers:

```
let floatArray = [12, 14.6, 35]
let stringArray = floatArray.map { String($0) }
let string = stringArray.joined(separator: "-")

print(string)
// prints "12.0-14.6-35.0"
```

Comment: I have a string which looks like: "[1,2,3]". Is there any way to easily convert this to an array [Int]? easily i.e. the reverse of what .description does?

Comment: @user2363025 uni can use JSON decoder. `try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: Data(string.utf8))`

Answer (score 49):

Swift 2.0 Xcode 7.0 beta 6 onwards uses `joinWithSeparator()` instead of `join()`:

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
let stringRepresentation = array.joinWithSeparator("-") // "1-2-3"
```

`joinWithSeparator` is defined as an extension on `SequenceType`

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String {
    /// Interpose the `separator` between elements of `self`, then concatenate
    /// the result.  For example:
    ///
    ///     ["foo", "bar", "baz"].joinWithSeparator("-|-") // "foo-|-bar-|-baz"
    @warn_unused_result
    public func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String
}
```

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 3**

```
["I Love","Swift"].joined(separator:" ") // previously joinWithSeparator(" ")
```

Comment: I would say that it is ["I Love","Swift"].joined(separator: " ")

Answer (score 21):

#### Since no one has mentioned reduce, here it is:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0].map {"\($0)"}.reduce("") { $0 + $1 } // "0110"
```

In the spirit of functional programming

Comment: Nice way of doing things, thanks... adding a shorter end of command line :  `[0,1,1,0].map{"\($0)"}.reduce("",+)`. 

Comment: @XLE_22 `[0,1,1,0].map(String.init).joined()`

Comment: Or faster: `...reduce(into: "") { $0 += $1 }`

Answer (score 16):

In Swift 4

```
let array:[String] = ["Apple", "Pear ","Orange"]

array.joined(separator: " ")
```

Answer (score 9):

To change an array of Optional/Non-Optional Strings

```
//Array of optional Strings
let array : [String?] = ["1",nil,"2","3","4"]

//Separator String
let separator = ","

//flatMap skips the nil values and then joined combines the non nil elements with the separator
let joinedString = array.flatMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: separator)


//Use Compact map in case of **Swift 4**
    let joinedString = array.compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: separator

print(joinedString)
```

Here **flatMap**, **compactMap** skips the nil values in the array and appends the other values to give a joined string.

Comment: @YashBedi In Swift 4 we use **compactMap** instead of **flatMap**

Comment: what meaning of "$" ?

Comment: @Augusto Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure's arguments by the names $0, $1, $2.

Here, $0 refer to the closure's first String arguments.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays, in iOS 13+ and macOS 10.15+, we might use `ListFormatter`:

```
let formatter = ListFormatter()

let names = ["Moe", "Larry", "Curly"]
if let string = formatter.string(from: names) {
    print(string)
}
```

That will produce a nice, natural language string representation of the list. A US user will see:

> Moe, Larry, and Curly

It will support any languages for which (a) your app has been localized; and (b) the user’s device is configured. For example, a German user with an app supporting German localization, would see:

> Moe, Larry und Curly

Answer (score 6):

You can either use loops for getting this done. Or by using map.

By mapping:

```
let array = ["one" , "two" , "three"]
    
array.map({$0}).joined(seperator : ",")
```

so in separator you can modify the string.

```
Output-> ("one,two,three")
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `joined()` to get a single **String** when you have array of struct also.

```
struct Person{
    let name:String
    let contact:String
}
```

You can easily produce string using `map()` & `joined()`

```
PersonList.map({"\($0.name) - \($0.contact)"}).joined(separator: " | ")
```

output:

```
Jhon - 123 | Mark - 456 | Ben - 789
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want convert custom object array to string or comma separated string (csv) you can use

```
 var stringIds = (self.mylist.map{$0.id ?? 0}).map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ",")
```

credit to : [urvish modi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5671103/urvish-modi) 
post: [Convert an array of Ints to a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774352/convert-an-array-of-ints-to-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 4):

Mine works on NSMutableArray with componentsJoinedByString

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
let stringRepresentation = array.componentsJoinedByString("-") // "1-2-3"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 2.2 you may have to cast your array to NSArray to use componentsJoinedByString(",")

```
let stringWithCommas = (yourArray as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString(",")
```

Comment: By the way this is just a translation of objective-c in swift.

Answer (score 3):

```
let arrayTemp :[String] = ["Mani","Singh","iOS Developer"]
    let stringAfterCombining = arrayTemp.componentsJoinedByString(" ")
   print("Result will be >>>  \(stringAfterCombining)")
```

Result will be >>>  Mani Singh iOS Developer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ditch empty strings in the array.

```
["Jet", "Fire"].filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: "-")
```

If you want to filter nil values as well:

```
["Jet", nil, "", "Fire"].flatMap { $0 }.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: "-")
```

Answer (score 2):

A separator can be a bad idea for some languages like Hebrew or Japanese.
Try this:

```
// Array of Strings
let array: [String] = ["red", "green", "blue"]
let arrayAsString: String = array.description
let stringAsData = arrayAsString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
let arrayBack: [String] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: stringAsData!)
```

For other data types respectively:

```
// Set of Doubles
let set: Set<Double> = [1, 2.0, 3]
let setAsString: String = set.description
let setStringAsData = setAsString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
let setBack: Set<Double> = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Set<Double>.self, from: setStringAsData!)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Swift equivalent to what you're describing is string interpolation. If you're thinking about things like JavaScript doing `"x" + array`, the equivalent in Swift is `"x\(array)"`.

As a general note, there is an important difference between string interpolation vs the `Printable` protocol. Only certain classes conform to `Printable`. *Every* class can be string interpolated somehow. That's helpful when writing generic functions. You don't have to limit yourself to `Printable` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can print any object using the print function

or use `\(name)` to convert any object to a string.

Example:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]

print(array) // prints "[1,2,3,4]"

let string = "\(array)" // string == "[1,2,3,4]"
print(string) // prints "[1,2,3,4]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create extension for an `Array`:

```
extension Array {

    var string: String? {

        do {

            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [.prettyPrinted])

            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        } catch {

            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have string array list , then convert to Int

```
let arrayList = list.map { Int($0)!} 
     arrayList.description
```

it will give you string value

Answer (score 0):

for any Element type

```
extension Array {

    func joined(glue:()->Element)->[Element]{
        var result:[Element] = [];
        result.reserveCapacity(count * 2);
        let last = count - 1;
        for (ix,item) in enumerated() {
            result.append(item);
            guard ix < last else{ continue }
            result.append(glue());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
let categories = dictData?.value(forKeyPath: "listing_subcategories_id") as! NSMutableArray
                        let tempArray = NSMutableArray()
                        for dc in categories
                        {
                            let dictD = dc as? NSMutableDictionary
                            tempArray.add(dictD?.object(forKey: "subcategories_name") as! String)
                        }
                        let joinedString = tempArray.componentsJoined(by: ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this when you want to convert list of struct type into string

```
struct MyStruct {
  var name : String
  var content : String
}

let myStructList = [MyStruct(name: "name1" , content: "content1") , MyStruct(name: "name2" , content: "content2")]
```

and covert your array like this way

```
let myString = myStructList.map({$0.name}).joined(separator: ",")
```

will produce ===>  `"name1,name2"`

Answer (score -1):

FOR SWIFT 3:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == phoneField
    {
        let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let components = newString.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)

        let decimalString = NSString(string: components.joined(separator: ""))
        let length = decimalString.length
        let hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.character(at: 0) == (1 as unichar)

        if length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || length > 11
        {
            let newLength = NSString(string: textField.text!).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length as Int

            return (newLength > 10) ? false : true
        }
        var index = 0 as Int
        let formattedString = NSMutableString()

        if hasLeadingOne
        {
            formattedString.append("1 ")
            index += 1
        }
        if (length - index) > 3
        {
            let areaCode = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("(%@)", areaCode)
            index += 3
        }
        if length - index > 3
        {
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", prefix)
            index += 3
        }

        let remainder = decimalString.substring(from: index)
        formattedString.append(remainder)
        textField.text = formattedString as String
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you question is something like this:
tobeFormattedString = ["a", "b", "c"]
Output = "abc"

`String(tobeFormattedString)`

Comment: No, this doesn't work. `String` has no initializer capable of doing that. Either you're using a custom extension or third-party library, or you're simply plainly mistaken.