# Append an array of strings to a string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I have an array of strings for one variable, and a string as another variable. I'd like to append all of the strings in the collection to the single string.

So for example I have:

```
 var s = String()

   //have the CSV writer create all the columns needed as an array of strings
   let arrayOfStrings: [String] = csvReport.map{GenerateRow($0)}

// now that we have all the strings, append each one 
        arrayOfStrings.map(s.stringByAppendingString({$0}))
```

the line above fails. I've tried every combination I can think of, but at the end of the day, I can't get it unless I just create a for loop to iterate through the entire collection, arrayOfStrings, and add it one by one. I feel like I can achieve this the same way using map or some other function.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: my answer was deleted with explanation "Code-only answers are considered low-quality and are liable to be deleted". you can use arrayOfStrings.reduce(s, combine: +).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [joined(separator:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined):

```
let stringArray = ["Hello", "World"]
let sentence = stringArray.joined(separator: " ")  // "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 7):

You could convert your array to string using `joinWithSeparator(String)`
here is an example

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
let stringRepresentation = array.joinWithSeparator("-") // "1-2-3"
```

source: [ [How do I convert a Swift Array to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string) ]

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options here. The most semantic choice is likely `joinWithSeparator` on the `[String]` object. This concatenates every string in the array, placing the separator provided as a parameter between each string.

```
 let result = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].joinWithSeparator("")
```

An alternative is to use a functional `reduce` and the + function operator which concatenates strings. This may be preferred if you want to do additional logic as part of the combine. Both example code produce the same result.

```
 let result = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].reduce("", combine: +)
```

It's also worth noting the second options is transferrable to any type that can be added, whereas the first only works with a sequence of strings, as it is defined on a protocol extension of `SequenceType where Generator.Element == String`.