# set text of label with array gives error "Cast from '[String]' to unrelated 'String' always fails

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uilabel

I am passing in an array via segue which works fine. I then want to set the text of a label with the array but the resulting screen comes up blank even though the print command is showing the array. Here is the code.

```
class MessageViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {


var passArrayForSegue = [String]()


@IBOutlet weak var arrayforSegue: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {


    print(passArrayForSegue)

    arrayforSegue.text = passArrayForSegue as? String

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the text of `arrayforSegue` which is a `UILabel`. The `.text` property has type `String` while your `passArrayForSegue` is of type `Array<String>` (you used the alternate way of declaring an array which is `[String]`). An easy way to set the `.text` property would be to iterate over the objects of your array and append them to a string.

**UPDATE**

You can see how to concatenate your array into a string in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly set a labels text to an array when it's expecting a string.  If you want to set the text to the contents of the array, you are going to need to iterate through it and get the strings from the array.