# Swift - Best practice to pass nested arrays into a function

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find references that can help me figure out how to work with nested arrays and passing them to functions. My Google game seems to be weak and I am heading down the preverbal rabbit hole and not finding what I am looking for. The idea is this I want to take a nested loop like so...

```
var array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to pass this nested array to a function where I want to then convert the inner arrays to strings and print them like so...
"123"
"456"
"789"

--Edit--
So far in trying to test this out I have the following...
    var arrayOfInt = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

```
func convertArray(array: [Int]) -> String{
   var innerArrayToString = array[0]

   for index in array[1...array.count]{
      print(String(index))
   }
   return innerArrayToString
}

convertArray()
```

Comment: don't ask for references, show the code you tried and explain what it does wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34315078/5327882),  you can try the following (Hints are in the code comments) :

```
var multiArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

// loop through your multiArray
for array in multiArray {

    // Turning an array of Int into String with a separator between numbers
    // In your case its only "" because you don't want to have separator like a dash for example
    let stringArray = array.flatMap({ String($0) })
    let stringRepresentationOfArray = stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(stringRepresentationOfArray)
}

// Output
// 123
// 456
// 789
```

Comment: I am reading up on the flatMap method now. We haven't really covered it and I understand the concept for the most part. So this really gives me something to look into. Thank you!

Comment: Great, that I could help you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the array length, just the data types, in order to create a function spec:

```
func processConversionList(list: [ [Int] ]) -> [String]
```

I'd suggest that this is just a wrapper which loops over the outer array and then calls the real processing function:

```
func processConversion(item: [Int]) -> String
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, but would like to understand what you mean.

Comment: Your question asked about nested arrays, but it seems actually that the single array yo string conversion was the real problem?