# iOS swift how do change matches?

Tags: ios, swift

i try matchesForRegexInText and number only success. but I'm want Double matches ...

example

(o) inputText : 1.00

(x) inputText : 1.0.0

(x) inputText : .01

i trying code

```
inputtexts.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tfta(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)  // text field changed event

func tfta(textField: UITextField) {
    let matches: [String] = matchesForRegexInText("[0-9]", text: textField.text)
    textField.text = arrayToString(matches)
}


func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

func arrayToString(strArr: [String]) -> String{
    var result = ""
    if strArr.count > 0 {
        for i in 0 ..< strArr.count {
            result += strArr[i]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need to wrap that `for` loop in `arrayToString`. If `strArr.count` is 0, then the `for loop` will just be skipped (as there are no elements in 0 .. < 0). Also, you can just use the built in `joinWithSeparator(_:)` function to do the job of `arrayToString`. Just set the separator to `""`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32256454/3141234

Comment: What shows up in the String array, and overall what results are you getting?

Comment: try code is input textfield in only number

Comment: but I want string "." input agree  and only one