# how can I join words from a String array to a single String, separated by a comma in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have an array of `String`s in my `Swift` app. I want to display them in a label, each of them separated by `,`. I tried this:

```
for hashtag in placeHashtags {
        text = text + "\(hashtag), "
    }

if (placeHashtags.count > 0){
    let text1 = text.remove(at: text.index(before: text.endIndex-1))
    text = text1.description
}
```

(the 2nd `if` is to remove the last comma), but then I do not see anything in my label.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string

Comment: The actual problem in your code is that `text.remove(at:)` returns the removed character, not the modified string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Write this:

```
let array = ["Hi", "Hello", "How", "Are", "You", "Fine"]
let joined = array.joined(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: Thanks Pragnesh, I will accept it as soon as I can :)