# Convert an array of Ints to a comma separated string

Tags: arrays, swift, closures

I know that if I want to convert an array of `Int`s to a `String`, I do this:

```
[0,1,1,0].map{"\($0)"}.reduce(""){$0+$1}
```

but I cannot figure out how would I convert an array of `Int`s to a comma separated `String`

Comment: @rmaddy In the question you linked as a duplicate, the accepted answer assumes an array of `String`s and therefore would not have answered the OP's question; it was missing the `map` step. So it's not an exact duplicate IMHO.

Comment: @idz That's true only if you look at the currently accepted answer. There are many answers and several show how to convert an array of numbers.

Comment: @rmaddy Fair point!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Well you can do it like :

```
let formattedArray = ([0,1,1,0].map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: var stringIds = ""
        
        if let tmpList = self.userList
        {
            stringIds = (tmpList.map{$0.id}).map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ",")
        }

user list is my custom objects array.

Comment: You don't actually need the parens around the array/map  `[0,1,1,0].map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ",")` is fine

Comment: You are my Steve Jobs

Comment: append missed ) at last sentence.. for fix it