# How to create url from int array

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an URL something like it
https://api.website.com/products?product_ids=1,2,3,4,5
Using integer array from CoreData

So far I do have this code

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]

var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "https"
urlComponents.host = "api.website.com"
urlComponents.path = "/products"
urlComponents.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "product_ids", value: ???????),
]
```

How can I add my array data to get a full URL I needed?
https://api.website.com/products?product_ids=1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an array of Ints to a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774352/convert-an-array-of-ints-to-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to map your array elements into a string and join the result using a comma:

```
let value = array.map(String.init).joined(separator: ",")
```