# Get all object from NSMutableArray into string using for loop

Tags: swift

In my code I have an `NSMutableArray`. I want to get all values from that array into `String` and I want to send to the server. I used a `for` loop but it doesn't work. I don't know what I did wrong. Please help to fix the issue.

Here the code I tried.

```
var newString1 = String()
for i in (0..<self.idMutableArray.count)
{
    newString1 = (idMutableArray.object(at: i) as! NSString) as String
    print("newString1 is ",newString1)
}
print("newString1 is ",newString1)
```

The mutable array Format is:

```
idMutableArray is  (
        31,
        30,
        29,
        42,
        50
    )
```

When I am tried I get this format:

```
newString1 is  29
newString1 is  30
newString1 is  31
newString1 is  42
newString1 is  50
```

But I want to send this format to the server.

```
newString1 = 31,30,29,42,50
```

I don't know how to change that array to string format. Please help me.

Comment: Why are you using `NSMutableArray` instead of a Swift array? Why `NSString` instead of `String`?

Comment: Why dont you iterate with the object instead? I mean: `for i in idMutableArray { newString = i as! NSString }`

Comment: I am new for Swift and don't know for how to use swift array?

Comment: Once you switch over to using a Swift array, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string

Comment: You don't need a loop for this, just use `componentsJoined` (or `joined` for a Swift array).

Comment: If you insist on using `NSArray`, see `NSArray componentsJoined`.

Comment: If you don't know how to use Swift arrays then you need to read the [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) section of the "The Swift Programming Language" book (along with the rest of the book).

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `NS` collection types in favor of standart Swift counterparts [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array) and [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary). You can start reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) if you want to find out more about them.

```
let idMutableArray = ["31", "30", "29", "42", "50"]
let newString1 = idMutableArray.joined(separator: ",")
```

However, if you have to use `NSMutableArray`, here is what you can do:

```
let idMutableArray = NSMutableArray(objects: "31", "30", "29", "42", "50")
let newString1 = idMutableArray.idMutableArray.componentsJoined(by: ",")

print(newString1) # will print "31,30,29,42,50"
```

Comment: While this is the most direct answer, the OP should not be using `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: let newString1 = idMutableArray.joined(separator: ",") it is got some validation problem in next functionality.

Comment: what do you mean by _validation problem_?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the values in **one** string, you should add them to that string and not to override it in each iteration.

```
var newString1 = ""
for i in (0..<idMutableArray.count)
{
    newString1 += String(describing: idMutableArray[i])
    if i < idMutableArray.count - 1 {
        newString1 += ","
    }
    print("newString1 is ",newString1)
}
print("newString1 is ",newString1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need `NSMutableArray`. Use Swift `Array`

```
let idMutableArray = ["31", "30", "29", "42", "50"]
```

Second of all you don't need a repeat loop, just `join` the strings.

```
let newString1 = idMutableArray.joined(separator: ",")
print("newString1 is ",newString1)
```

Comment: Given the code in the question, it appears to be an array of `NSString`, not an array of numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about the array dump (missing double quotes)

Comment: let newString1 = idMutableArray.joined(separator: ",") it is got some validation problem in next functionality.

Comment: Change all Foundation types to Swift types. It's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a new value to your string each time your `for` loop runs:

```
newString1 = (idMutableArray.object(at: i) as! NSString) as String
```

You can use [joined(separator:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641243-joined) to get the desired output:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let string = array.joined(separator: ",")
print("\(string)") // Prints "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: This is wrong. It prints `1,2,3,4,5,`. Note the trailing comma.