# How to convert a string as json to simple string - SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift3, swifty-json

I have a string as json like this:

```
[
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/6861\/A.jpg",
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/6861\/B.jpg",
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/6861\/C.jpg"
]
```

I want to convert it to a string (separated with comma ):

```
http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6861/A.jpg,http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6861/B.jpg,http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6861/C.jpg
```

---

```
let json = JSON(stringLiteral: urls)
```

but after print `json` variable it shows:

```
[
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/3156\/A.jpg",
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/3156\/B.jpg",
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/3156\/C.jpg",
  "http:\/\/kashanmap.ir\/media\/k2\/galleries\/3156\/D.jpg"
]
```

Comment: `let json = JSON(stringLiteral: urls)` That's an Array. Then you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you can wait for Swift 4, converting between Swift objects and json will be built into the language.

Comment: ok, now how can I convert my string to array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Swift Array to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the joined function with a comma separator

```
let stringArrayCities = ["Reno", "Austin", "Miami"]
let combinedstringArrayCitiesComma = stringArrayCities.joined(separator: ",")
print(combinedstringArrayCitiesComma)
// prints Reno,Austin,Miami
```