# Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x106d27d88) to 'NSString' (0x107be3c40)

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, json, swift

I'm trying to download and filter json data. After filtering json data, i printed that filtered data which is working fine. But when i try to append that data to string type of array its gets crash and error is :-

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x106d27d88) to 'NSString'
>   (0x107be3c40).

[code sample and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEbV5.png)

Comment: Please post your code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Also, your `productName` is actually an array, it has all those elements, so it can't be converted to String.

Comment: +1 on both @ShamasS's comments. Also, you seem to use Swift 3, get rid of NSArray, NSString, and other Foundation (too Objective-C) stuff, and prefers the Swift ones (it's almost the same without the `NS` prefix).

Comment: when posting try to generalize the question so it is easier to search and contextualize. e.g. 0x106d27d88 applies only to your machine at the time of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

cast that productName as array of string like this. [String]

`let productName = jsonObj?.value(forKey: "name") as! [String]`

then follow this links

1) https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-join-an-array-of-strings-into-a-single-string

2) [How do I convert a Swift Array to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string)

Example

```
let productName1 = ["1", "2", "3"]

var arrayForName1 = [String]()

arrayForName1 = ["name"]

let str = productName1.joined(separator: "")
// ["name", "123"]

// or
let str1 = productName1.joined(separator: ", ")
// ["name", "1, 2, 3"]

arrayForName1.append(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `productName` is an array and you are casting it to String so that causes your problem. You have two options to fix this base:

1. Validate your `productName` array and find the correct index of the actual string to append to your `arrayForName1` array. So your code will look like

   `arrayForName1.append(productName[0])`
2. If your `productName` is an array of string and you want to add all of them to `arrayForName1`, simply use this code

   `arrayForName1 += productName`

Answer (score 0):

Into Your  **json data** Array are give with any Parameter (like: Number = ["1", "2", "3"] )

```
var Number1:String? = ""
var NumberList:[String] = []

if let Number_from = anItem["Number"] as? String {
  self.Number1 = Number_from
  self.NumberList.append(self.Number1!)
} else {
  self.NumberList.append("Not Available")
}
```