# Join Array of Strings into a single String starting from a particular index of Array with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift3

So I have Full Name text field, I created `nameComponents` Array by splitting full Name by space. Now I want to take 0 index element as first name and rest of components as last name. I like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string) approach of joining string array in Swift. Is there any way to join the array starting from a particular index (in my case index 1). I don't want to use loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dropFirst()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688121-dropfirst) or [dropFirst(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688675-dropfirst)

**dropFirst()**

```
  let names = "Steve Jobs Nojobs".components(separatedBy: " ")
  let firstName = names.first!
  let lastName = names.dropFirst().joined(separator: " ")
  print(firstName)//Steve
  print(lastName)//Jobs Nojobs
```

**dropFirst(_:)**

```
 let names = "It is a long name".components(separatedBy: " ")
 let lastName = names.dropFirst(2).joined(separator: " ")        
 print(lastName)//a long name
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to fully split the string into an array if you only want to separate it at the first space.
You can locate the first space and determine the parts preceding and following it directly.
Example (Swift 3):

```
let string = "foo bar baz"

if let range = string.range(of: " ") {
    let firstPart = string.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
    let remainingPart = string.substring(from: range.upperBound)

    print(firstPart)        // foo
    print(remainingPart)    // bar baz
}
```

In Swift 4 you would extract the parts with

```
    let firstPart = String(string[..<range.lowerBound])
    let remainingPart = String(string[range.upperBound...])
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent Objective-C Solution?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR: Sure. NSString has rangeOfString, substringToIndex and substringFromIndex methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Swift3:

```
let array = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]
let str = array[1..<array.count].joined(separator: "-")
// po str
// "one-two-three"
```

Answer (score 0):

For particular this question you can do this way:

1. Remove first element of array to you variable;
2. Now, last part is your last name.

Example:

```
var nameComponents = ["My", "name", "is"]

let firstName = nameComponents.remove(at: 0) // "My"
let lastName = nameComponents.joined(separator: " ") // "name is"
```

But more practical way is to use [array subscript by passing `Range`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2885139-subscript) to it.

```
let firstName = nameComponents.first!

// Swift 3
let lastName = nameComponents[1..<nameComponents.count].joined(separator: " ")

// Swift 4
let lastName = nameComponents[1...].joined(separator: " ")
```