# How to display an array in a label

Tags: arrays, swift, label

How do I display an array/the elements of an array in a label? I'm updating the elements each time so they will change from underscores to letters as more buttons are pressed in a game of hangman.

"random" is the animal randomly generated from a different array.

```
    if random == "aardvark" {
        theWord.text = "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"

    }


}


@IBAction func aPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if random == "aardvark" {
    if aardvark[0] == "a" {
        aar[0] = "a"
    };if aardvark[1] == "a" {
        aar[1] = "a"
    };if aardvark[2] == "a" {
        aar[2] = "a"
    };if aardvark[3] == "a" {
        aar[3] = "a"
    };if aardvark[4] == "a" {
        aar[4] = "a"
    };if aardvark[5] == "a" {
        aar[5] = "a"
    };if aardvark[6] == "a" {
        aar[6] = "a"
    };if aardvark[7] == "a" {
        aar[7] = "a"
    }
    else if aardvark[0] != "a" , aardvark[1] != "a" , aardvark[2] != "a" , aardvark[3] != "a" , aardvark[4] != "a" , aardvark[5] != "a" , aardvark[6] != "a" , aardvark[7] != "a" {
        wrong += 1
    }

    **theWord.text = self.aar**
```

that's my problem^^

since the more correct letters pressed, the more of the word will be revealed (from underscores to letters guessed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Swift's `join` method, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string).

So in your case, it'd be:

`self.aar.join("")`

which would be the aar array joined on the empty string, meaning all elements concatenated (as long as they are strings themselves, which it seems they are).