# Merge array elements with "\n" into String in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I'm trying to merge array of string with `\n`, but didn't get any solution. I have following types of array which contains section names.

```
let arrSectionName = [
    "Section 1",
    "Section 2",
    "Section 3",
    "Section 4",
    "Section 5",
    "Section 6",
]
```

Now, I want this string from above array:

> "Section 1 \nSection 2 \nSection 3 \nSection 4 \nSection 5 \nSection
>   6"

So Finally message should display as follow:

**Alert Message Output:**

```
    Following section which are still pending to complete, please verify and try again:
    Section 1
    Section 2
    Section 3
    Section 4
    Section 5
    Section 6
```

Section name are dynamic, which will be change runtime and store in `arrSectionName`.

Comment: You are not "splitting", you are "joining".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined

Comment: @rmaddy, you right. `joined` function work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Similar discussion at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [joined(separator:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined). It joins the array elements and adds the given separator string between the elements.

```
let str = arrSectionName.joined(separator: " \n")
```