# How to collect the multiple dynamic value and store in array from tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am choosing table view cells using check mark functionality and have to save that values in an array (only checkmark cells names) and those array values I have to pass in url parameters (POST) (example: Dhoni,Kohili,Rohit)

here is my code  I have to save "SwithTableView" cells data

```
var checked = [Bool]()


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == switchTableView{
       return self.arrdata20.count
    } else
    {
        return self.arrdata.count
    }

    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (tableView == self.switchTableView)
    {

        let cell:switchTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! switchTableViewCell

        cell.nameLbl.text = (arrdata20[indexPath.row].name)
        print(cell.nameLbl.text)

        if (arrdata20[indexPath.row].emp_id == DataManager.sharedInstance.empID)
        {
            cell.isHidden=true
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden=false
        }
        if checked[indexPath.row] == false{
            cell.accessoryType = .none


        } else if checked[indexPath.row] {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark


        }


        return cell

    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switchTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let cell = switchTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {

        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            checked[indexPath.row] = false
            print(indexPath.row)

        } else  {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            checked[indexPath.row] = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For i  in 0..<arrdata20.count  (or arrdata) if  checked[i] == true youaarray.append ((arrdata20i].name) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extra array to keep the selection is bad practice and very hard to maintain for example if cells can be inserted, deleted or moved.

**It's highly recommended to store the information in the data model**

In your struct add a member `isSelected`

```
struct Jsonstruct20 : Decodable {
    let name, emp_id : String

    var isSelected = false

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, emp_id }
}
```

```
var checked = [Bool]()
```

In `cellForRow` set the checkmark depending on `isSelected` (I removed redundant code)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard tableView == self.switchTableView else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! switchTableViewCell
    let item = arrdata20[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLbl.text = item.name
    print(cell.nameLbl.text)
    cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.isHidden = item.emp_id == DataManager.sharedInstance.empID
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectRowAt` just toggle `isSelected` and reload the row to update the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    guard tableView == self.switchTableView else { return }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    arrdata20[indexPath.row].isSelected = !arrdata20[indexPath.row].isSelected
    // or in Swift 4.2+ arrdata20[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

To get all names of the selected cells filter the data source array

```
let selectedNames = Array(arrdata20.lazy.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name})
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation and I am getting error in this line     arrdata20[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
Value of type 'Bool' has no member 'toggle'

Comment: I am getting the TB cell response from server in my code I have  'struct jsonstruct20:Decodable {
    var name:String
    var emp_id:String
//    var isSelected = false
//    let name : String
}'.  if I add isSelected and name the response not coming Asit has no value from server so how I call model in my cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Regarding `toggle()`: This was introduced in Swift 4.2. You are encouraged to update you Swift version. Or use `arrdata20[indexPath.row].isSelected = !arrdata20[indexPath.row].isSelected`. Regarding the struct: Add `private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, emp_id }` to decode only name and id.

Comment: can you please update code based on this new scenario

Comment: I updated the answer. Please conform to the naming convention that struct names start with a capital letter (`Jsonstruct20`)

Comment: now for  this updated code, response is coming but the issue is if I am selecting cell cells another cell is deselecting and to to select some cell I have to press 4 or 5 times to activate checkmark this issue is there and I printed the list of checkmark its coming like this

Comment: LazyMapBidirectionalCollection<LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection<Array<jsonstruct20>>, String>(_base: Swift.LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection<Swift.Array<hubnr.jsonstruct20>>(_base: [hubnr.jsonstruct20(name: "Vamsi", emp_id: "001", isSelected: false), hubnr.jsonstruct20(name: "Anil", emp_id: "002", isSelected: true), hubnr.jsonstruct20(name: "Raj", emp_id: "003", isSelected: false), hubnr.jsonstruct20(name: "Nithin", emp_id: "004", isSelected: true),                          as I need output like (name1,name2,name4) like this as I need to pass that values in  parameter [POST Method]

Comment: wrap the `filter` expression in `Array(...)`. I updated the answer.

Comment: it's working perfect but the thing is my output (selectedNames) is saving as.      ["title1","title2"].        can you please convert this to      "title1,title2"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string