# Reduce to concatenate String Array? Faster solution?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, concatenation, reduce

I use code like this to build one string from an string array:

```
class ActionCMD {   // "class" to avoid value copies when updating string members
    var cmds = [String]()   // simply the list of all strings to speed up inserting
    var cmd : String { return cmds.reduce("", +) }   // resulting string
}
```

But for 35.000 strings it needs 15 min. Is there a better (quicker) way to do the concatenating?

Comment: How about `return cmds.joined()`

Comment: How do you get your input set of 35000 `String`? Perhaps  some preprocessing can be made to speed things up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25827033/1187415

Comment: Is it definitely this code that takes 15 minutes and not the loading of the 35,000 strings?

Comment: Do you have an idea about the character count of the strings in `cmds`?

Comment: Executing your code, the `reduce`,  in a playground takes 0.0003 seconds for me on a few year old MacBook Pro so even though my test is far from precise I feel the issue must lay somewhere else for you

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid creating intermediate strings. Instead, mutate the previously accumulated string, by using either:

```
cmds.reduce(into: "", { $0 += $1 })
```

or :

```
cmds.joined()
```

or simply :

```
var cmd = ""
for i in cmds.indices {
    cmd += cmds[i]
}
```

---

<sup>More on String concatenation [here](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2018/03/09/faster-swift-string-concatenation/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I will try "joined". I don't use a loop to do it by my own. Like to use library functions.

Comment: Its now fast! :-) I think 30 s instead of minutes! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Peter71 That's quite a difference! Glad I could be of help :)