# How convert and join Array to String in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, join, swift5

I have:

let array = ["a", "1", "b"]

Expected result:

let result = "a1b"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a Swift Array to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

**[Character] -> String:**

```
let characterArray: [Character] = ["a", "1", "b"]

let string = String(characterArray)

print(string)
// prints "a1b"
```

**[String] -> String:**

```
let string = stringArray.joined(separator: " ")

print(string)
// prints "a1b"
```