# How can i show an array in label ? With ","

Tags: swift

In this way, I print my array in the array, but how can I show it to the user by putting a comma between them in the label? Like this;
technology, event, founder

```
let item = event?.feed_category
     item?.forEach({ items in
        arr.append(items.title ?? "")
     })
lblEventCategory.text = arr //this line incorrect
```

Comment: You have to convert the array to string. Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827033/how-do-i-convert-a-swift-array-to-a-string

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). You might be able to delete the post yourself as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of strings can be joined by `,` using:

`arr.joined(separator: ",")`

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/joined(separator:)-5do1g

Answer (score 0):

since your array, `arr` may contain empty string `""`, you may want to remove them, using this approach:

```
print("----> arr: \(arr.filter{!$0.isEmpty}.joined(separator: ","))")
```