# Writing an Int-Array to a text file

Tags: arrays, swift, join, integer

I need to write a dictionary to a text file. I couldn't find anything handy. But writing an array is solved only for strings:

```
let pieces = [ "1", "5", "1", "4" ]
let joined = "\n".join(pieces)
```

How could I join integers without creating my own loop?

If there is a simple solution for dictionary itself, that would be better! ;-)

Comment: Read and write on file is pretty easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097826/read-and-write-data-from-text-file.

Comment: Here usefull tip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581324/swift-how-can-string-join-work-custom-types

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I searched for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an array of `Int`

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And you want to concatenate the **text representations** of these numbers **without writing a loop** right?

You can write this:

```
let joined = "\n".join( numbers.map { "\($0)" } )
```

Now `joined` has this value: `"1\n2\n3\n4\n5"`

Hope this helps.